# IBM Case MAnager EDS to populate grid

Tags: ibm-case-manager

We are looking for a way to query an external API and populate the result in a grid in case view or on a task, depending on complexity.

Reading through The EDS documentation it sounds very restrictive to case fields.

If I have a custom widget with a grid, can I use EDS to call a REST API and populate the result into the grid? (Assuming that authentication is not a problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are probably looking for are external properties.
Take a look at the documentation [Knowledge Center - Case Managet: Using external properties](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSCTJ4_5.3.1/com.ibm.casemgmt.development.doc/acmdv135.htm)